# testing subscriptions - can't cancel

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have my in-app subscription working using a second test account.  Now when I check inventory using queryInventoryAsync the subscription shows up as expected.

So now I want to do some more testing.  I want to cancel the subscription and then when I know that works, I want to test again.

However, when I go to Google Play -> My Apps on the same phone as I used to buy the subscription, it shows no subscriptions!  So I can't cancel it.  What is wrong?

Also, how can I test expiration of subscription and make Google think time has passed.
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Google does not support testing of subscriptions.  You have to use real charges.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the subscription have to go to the Google Wallet web. It's the only way, you can't do it in-app.

To testing process. You can use a subscription with trial time, in this way you haven't to pay until this trial time finish and you can test at least the purchase flow.

Also you "only" have to wait a week to see the subscription expired, and without make a refund if you had cancelled before.